# Slow MySQL Queries (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql, performance, wordpress, indexing

My webhost suspended my account due to mysql overload caused by my blog. They asked me to examine the slow queries and fix the problem by "indexing" them, but I can't quite understand what should I do here:

```
# Query_time: 1.116245  Lock_time: 0.000202 Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 3486
use mydbname
select tag, t.tag_id, count(p2t.post_id) as count, ((count(p2t.post_id)/1070)*100) as weight, ((count(p2t.post_id)/109)*100) as relativeweight
  from wp_tags t inner join wp_post2tag p2t on t.tag_id = p2t.tag_id
  inner join wp_posts p on p2t.post_id = p.ID
  WHERE post_date_gmt < '2011-12-06 09:00:01'
  AND (post_type = 'post')
  group by t.tag
  order by weight desc
  LIMIT 10

# Tue Dec  6 02:00:08 2011
# Query_time: 6.926785  Lock_time: 1.731793 Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 3486
use mydbname
select tag, t.tag_id, count(p2t.post_id) as count, ((count(p2t.post_id)/1070)*100) as weight, ((count(p2t.post_id)/109)*100) as relativeweight
  from wp_tags t inner join wp_post2tag p2t on t.tag_id = p2t.tag_id
  inner join wp_posts p on p2t.post_id = p.ID
  WHERE post_date_gmt < '2011-12-06 09:00:01'
  AND (post_type = 'post')
  group by t.tag
  order by weight desc
  LIMIT 10
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't do much, since the code generating this queries and database structure are not yours, and rewriting wordpress would take months of work.

But there is one or two things you can do.

1. Problem queries contain wp_post2tag table, which belongs not to wordpress itself, but to Ultimate Tag Warrior plugin. Maybe deleting or disabling this plugin could help.
2. You can try to upgrade wordpress and all plugins to latest version, maybe problem was already solved.
3. By default WP uses not-so-optimal but avaiable everywhere MyISAM tables. You can try to migrate your database to InnoDB tables. But I would not advise doing it, if you don't have strong grip on how mysql works.

Comment: Are you sure its UTW? Cause its just ONE of the several queries in the slow query log: http://cl.ly/3f3B3d0Q081k1g0i2l1d   Thanks!

Comment: @Nimbuz well, EXPLAIN from your other comment shows it as a culprit, and it have quite a bad reputation. In your slow log, there some of most basic queries, that have no real reason to be executed so long - except for being blocked out of resources by long-running UTW queries.

Answer (score 3):

Before you do anything else, upgrade to the most recent version of WordPress and import your UTW tag structures to WordPress's built-in term architecture; if you upgrade to WP 3.x before doing the import you'll have to use an import plugin like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/utw-importer/).  It's still not the most efficient sql I've ever seen, but it's cleaner than the UTW tag sql, which wasn't internal to WordPress.

I would generally agree with @Nameless's point #1, except that since you're seeing these queries cause problems on your blog I imagine you're using the UTW tag functionality, and you'll need to migrate the tag structure from UTW to native WordPress terms before you can deactivate UTW, or you're likely to lose features you rely on.

Unless you're having other, unrelated to UTW, MySQL issues, I would not suggest trying to switch to InnoDB; unless you've a very high traffic site I don't think the win from switching table types is going to be worth the pain of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You need you use EXPLAIN to see plan of your query and it will show you what can be optimized.
I suspect the problem is with group and order parts.

Comment: Can you have opportunity to added indexes to database and can you copy it to your sever to play with it and optimize?

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_posts:  INDEX(post_type, post_date_gmt)  -- in this order
wp_post2tag:  INDEX(post_id, tag_id)        -- in this order
```

And remove all references to `wp_tags` and change `GROUP BY t.tag` `GROUP BY p2t.tag_id`, which will have the same effect, but be faster.

Meanwhile, the computation is wrong since the `JOINs` happen before the `COUNT()` is done.  So the number is probably grossly inflated.

If you want more discussion pleas provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.